# Legend customisation in groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have a `groupplot` in which each plot shows only part of the data--the first shows one out of five datasets while the second shows the remaining four. For space and aesthetic reasons, however, I want to show the legend of all the data in the first plot.

I guess one solution is that I could plot the four "missing" data sets in the first plot in white to hide them, but this will hide part of the data set that I do want to show. To prevent this, I would need to change the order of the data sets, which I do want.

The only solution I can see at the moment is that I manually draw the legend using TikZ commands, but this seems awkward.

Here's the MWE that illustrates my problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,width=5cm,height=5cm,
  group style={group size=1 by 2}]
  \nextgroupplot  
  \addplot[color=black] coordinates {(-0.9,0.9) (0.9,-0.9)}; 
  \addplot[color=red] coordinates {(-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9)}; 
  \legend{a,b};
  \nextgroupplot  
  \addplot[color=black] coordinates {(-0.9,0.9) (0.9,-0.9)}; 
  \addplot[color=red] coordinates {(-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9)}; 
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives

[image]

which has the legend I want, but in the first plot, I do not want the red line to appear (without affecting the legend).

Comment: You can use `\addlegendimage`, similar to for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258238/missing-legend-entries-in-groupplot/258333#258333

Comment: Perfect. It wasn't clear from the manual that I can customise the color. If you want to add a proper answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\addlegendimage{red}` instead of the `\addplot` in the first `groupplot`. Optionally define styles for each dataset.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  plot1/.style={black},
  plot2/.style={red}
  ]
\begin{groupplot}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,width=5cm,height=5cm,
  group style={group size=1 by 2}]
  \nextgroupplot  
  \addplot[plot1] coordinates {(-0.9,0.9) (0.9,-0.9)}; 
  \addlegendimage{plot2}
  \legend{a,b};
  \nextgroupplot  
  \addplot[plot1] coordinates {(-0.9,0.9) (0.9,-0.9)}; 
  \addplot[plot2] coordinates {(-0.9,-0.9) (0.9,0.9)}; 
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]